# How to explode serialize string inside string with Regex

Tags: php, regex, serialization

I have some string, and contains with serialize data.

**Example**

```
{waku:community id=1} just published an event {waku:event id=9 type=story}
```

**Implement**

```
        preg_match_all('/\{(waku:[^}]+)\}/', $str, $matches);
        foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $elem) {
            $prop = explode('&', preg_replace('/\s+/', '&', $elem));
            $type = substr(array_shift($prop), strlen('waku:'));
            var_dump($prop);
        }
```

This code is doesn't work,

**output**

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "id=1"
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "id=9"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "type=story"
}
```

How to explode that string to get the type of **waku:type(community/event)** and the **id** of it?

I hope you can fix this question.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have tried, but i always get something that is i didnt want

Comment: Better to show your attempt in question even if it is not working.

Comment: @anubhava updated... Can you help me?

Comment: Can you also tell what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every waku element has **type** and **id**, you can recognize them in regex:

```
preg_match_all('/\{waku:(\w+)\s+id=(\d+)\s*([^}]*)\}/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $type = $match[1];
    $id = $match[2];
    $otherParameters = $match[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$str = '{waku:community id=1} just published an event {waku:event id=9 type=story}';
$arr = array();
preg_replace_callback('~\{\s*waku:(?:community|event)\s*(.+?)\}~s',
    function ($m) use (&$arr) { if (preg_match_all('~[^=\s]+=[^\s=]+~', $m[1], $w))
        $arr[] = $w[0]; }, $str);
print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id=1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => id=9
            [1] => type=story
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{waku:\S+\s(id=\d+)\s*(type=[^}]+)?}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/8

```
$re = "/{waku:\\S+\\s(id=\\d+)\\s*(type=[^}]+)?}/";
$str = "{waku:community id=1} just published an event {waku:event id=9 type=story}";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```